# Configure virtual page size in linux

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

I'm testing CPU's hardware prefetcher.
It is known that the prefetching occurs up to a page boundary.
I want to make sure that my test works right.

Anybody know how I can change virtual page size in linux?

Comment: Usually CPU hardware has a fixed page size that cannot be altered in software. What CPU architecture are you on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On x86-64, the only page sizes supported by the hardware are 4kb and 2MB. 4kb is used by default; for 2MB pages, you can use Linux's [hugetlb](http://linuxgazette.net/155/krishnakumar.html) system to allocate them.

Comment: Actually the hugepages are [2M on x86_64](http://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages#x86_64).  At least, they are on every x86_64 system I have ever seen.  (We use hugepages extensively where I work; they can provide a significant performance boost when working with large data sets.)